# How to save an image to a specific line in a word document trough python

Tags: python, automation

```
import os
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

path = 'file_path'

doc = Document()

tabela = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=5)

for i, archive in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
    if arquivo.endswith('.jpg') or arquivo.endswith('.png'):

        archive_path = os.path.join(archive_path, archive)

        tabela.add_row()

        cell = tabela.cell(i // 2, i % 2)

        cell.paragraphs[0].add_run().add_picture(archive_path, width=Inches(4), height=Inches(3))

doc.save('doc_path')
```

> This should copy the image from a certain path an paste it in the table of the word document and it does that . My problem is : is there any way of copy and pasting it without the table in a certain position of the word document?Im automating a report and that is the only thing left to do and i cant figure it out ...